# How do I skip an iteration step in a while loop in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl I'm trying to achieve this:

```
while ($row = <$fh>){
     if the row contains the character >:
          #do something AND then skip to the next line
     else:
         #continue to parse normally and do other things
```

Comment: Have you heard of regex?

Comment: My problem was the skip, clearly illustrated below. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can skip to the next iteration of a loop with the [`next` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html). Since you are reading line by line, that's all you need to do.

For checking if the character is present, use [a regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). That's done with the [`m//` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) and `=~` in Perl.

```
while ($row = <$fh>) {
  if ( $row =~ m/>/ ) {
    # do stuff ...
    next;
  }
  # no need for else
  # continue and do other stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
while ($row = <$fh>)
{
    if($row =~ />/)
    {
        #do something AND then skip to the next line
        next;
    }
    #continue to parse normally and do other things
}
```